# WebSockets - стриминг данных

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

как через сокеты реализовать стриминг даты и время с сервера? то есть, каждую секунду отправлять правильные дату и время на клиент

также интересует, как повесить обработчик, который будет оповещать при изменение определенного файла? то есть, некий callback, который вызывается при изменении файла

(NodeJS)

Спасибо

Comment: Вопрос не конкретный, попробуйте переформулировать. Что значит "стриминг даты"? В моем представлении это "каждую секунду отправлять правильные дату и время на клиент" (может быть с рядом оптимизации вроде "кидать дату только при её изменении). Что значит "**обработчик**, который будет оповещать о изменении файла?" Это что, callback, который вызывается при изменении файла?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы..именно это я и хочу

Comment: подправил вопрос, сейчас более понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчет обработчика, который следит за изменениями - 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Каждую секунду отправлять дату и время на клиент:

```
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit(Date.now());
},1000);
```